# How to change fonts color in Installshield 2011?

Tags: installation, installshield, installshield-2011

How can I change fonts color in the the default dialogs in Installshield 2011?

I have created a new entry (with the new color) into TexStile Table, but when selects the new "test style" in the Dialog editor, the colour does not change. 
This works fine in InstallShield 2010.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the setup. Selected color does not reflect immediately in dialog designer view. You have to build the project and start installation and then verify it on corresponding dialog.

Comment: Yes in run time works OK but in desing time do not work neither after close and open the project. Ok, running OK in run time it is enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here goes

- Change the TextStyle property of the text control from default to
  any font example Arial10White
- Save the and close the project.
- open the project >> Installation Designer >> Expand Additinal Tools

  - Select the Direct Editor Table
  - Choose the Text Style Table
  - Select the Fonts need to change the color set the color code generated from RGB Formula ( narrated in textstyle topic help ) for example for white i choose 16777215  save the table .
    Open the wizard and click edit layout  you can see the Color is reflected :)
    Below is the Screen shot

[Text Style font color editing from Install Sheild 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsGmb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add new "test style", then save your project or close your project and re-open it.